# Python 3.4 giving same epoch time with or without '%z'?

Tags: python-3.x, epoch

My code runs on python 3 giving epoch time - however, it gives identical time of 1389458028 irrespective the value for z - below is my code:

```
import time

def epoch_time():    
    d = '11/Jan/2014:08:33:48 -0500'
    p='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z'
    aa = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(d , p)))
    return aa   

print (epoch_time())
```

What should be the fix?

Comment: Why don't you use `time.time()`?

Comment: @cdonts - time.time() does not take any arguments. In this case, I am trying to convert into epoch time. If you are sure, pls provide a code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.strptime()` parses the timezone, but `time.mktime()` doesn't use the `tm_gmtoff` field in the struct_time object. As the documentation says, it works as the reverse to localtime() and doesn't care about time zones.

You can either use the `datetime` module

```
import datetime

def epoch_time(d):
    p = '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z'
    a = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, p)
    aa = a.timestamp()
    return aa
```

or use the tm_gmtoff field of the `time.strptime()` result and your  local timezone to calculate the offset between the timestamp you get and the real UTC timestamp.

Comment: `tm_gmtoff` is no member in Python 3.2. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time) `Changed in version 3.3: The struct_time type was extended to provide the tm_gmtoff and tm_zone attributes when platform supports corresponding struct tm members.`

Comment: @HelloWorld: Yes, but the question title mentions Python 3.4. As you wrote yourself it exists since version 3.3.

Comment: You are right, I mixed the versions. When commenting I had Py 3.2 in mind (by the OP).

Comment: @cg909 - I had errors when I tried to run it on Python3.4. It says "NameError: name 'dt' is not defined" when I used "aa = dt.timestamp(a)" - not "a" inside the parenthisis

Comment: Sorry, it should be `a` not `dt`.